# Including a body in a GET, PUT, or POST request results in response of "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app"?

Tags: rest, https, amazon-cloudfront

The short story: If I hit my endpoint /api/something with a PUT and no body, it goes through to my Lambda (via CF -> API GW -> Lambda). If I add a body to the request, it doesn't work and seems to die before hitting the API Gateway. I'm not sure why it would do this.

The long story:
I've set up a CloudFront distribution that sends requests to /api to our API gateway and all other requests just vend static website resources.

It has been working great so far for our simple use cases. We previously only hit the API Gateway with GET requests, but now we're going to start needing to send PUT or POST requests to the API Gateway. I had to update the CloudFront distribution "behaviors" for the /api path pattern (the one going to the API gateway) to allow all HTTP methods after that, I was able to start getting responses from the API Gateway for PUT and POST responses (previously only worked for GET).

However, I noticed that if I try to send a payload or body with the request (regardless of the request type), I don't think it actually hits the API Gateway or the Lambda that the API Gateway is routing to because I get a response of "You need to enable JavaScript to run this app". I tried looking at the logs but couldn't find anything. The heads shows "Error from cloudfront" but I'm not sure why or where to find what the error was.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this or what the issue might be?

---

Update (10/8): I figured out the "enable javascript" thing was coming up because of my custom error pages for 403&404 errors. I deleted them in my development environment and now get a clearer error.

> "This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method
> that was used for this request. The distribution supports only
> cachable requests. We can't connect to the server for this app or
> website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a
> configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website
> owner."

However, I still don't know what to do, as the request type (PUT) is enabled and the request works as long as I don't provide a body. Not sure how to get it to be ok with a body at the moment.